# python regex to split list entry's name into list name and index

Tags: python, regex

How can I use regular expressions to parse `<listname>[#]` into `[listname, #]`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
> s = 'li[10]'
> re.split(s,r'[%d]')
['[%d]']
> re.findall(s,r'[%d]')
[]
> s.split(r'[%d]')
['li[0]']
```

the desired output is `li` and `10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `(.*)\[(.*)\]`?

```
re.findall("(.*)\[(.*)\]", s)

# [('li', '10')]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should put your pattern as the first part of the `findall` command as `findall( pattern, string)`.  You pattern is only matching a single digit ie: `0` through `9`.  To match more than 1 digit you can use:

```
 re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]', s)
```

This will return just the digits, and not the square brackets.  To get the stuff in from the brackets you can use:

```
re.findall(r'(\w)\[(\d+)\]', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can also suggest a more restrictive pattern to use with `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'(\w+)\[(\d+)]', s)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/a53Sh9)

Or a variation with `zip`:

```
import re
s = 'li[10] li[11]'
names, ids = zip(*re.findall(r"(\w+)\[(\d+)]", s))
print(names)
print(ids)
```

See [another Python demo](http://ideone.com/KICcfk)

*Details*:

- `(\w+)`  - Group 1 capturing one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `\[` - a `[` literal symbol
- `(\d+)`  - Group 2 capturing 1 or more digits
- `]` - a closing literal `]` symbol